# how to make a new tab like find bugs in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, settings

I'd like to make a plugin and I don't now how to create a new tab for it like the picture above. Is there any template for this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN4mb.jpg

[image]

Comment: It's called preferences I think, try looking for that.

Comment: I think I am on the right track. I searched with the properties word and I found nothing. Maybe with this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The Eclipse platform supports preferences for persisting data between
>   application restarts. Preferences are stored as key / value pairs. The
>   key is an arbitrary String. The value can be a boolean, String, int or
>   another primitive type....

[this is a tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html) where you can generate a preference tab that can looks like this:

[image]